# Can't reinstall apps from SD card after reboot

Tags: applications, google-play-store, sd-card, installation, storage

This is the first time my phone randomly rebooted, I didn't think much of it until all my apps disappeared. The apps in the internal storage is still there but the apps that was moved to the SD were all gone. I went to the play store to try to get them back but it won't install.

Please help

LG - SP320

Comment: clone the (broken?) sdcard to another one and try to reboot until your sdcard is detected again (loose tray?)